# What's the difference between male and female voice?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, fourier, fourier-series, voice

If I record the voice of a man and a woman, what are the main differences I get in the various spectra and harmonics in Fourier analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between female and make voice is the pitch range of the fundamental frequency (of all vowels and consonants that have a pitch). The difference is significant: it's on average a factor of two or thereabouts.

Female also tend to have higher ranges but the relevance of this depends highly on the specific language and the difference is somewhat less significant.